# MySQL - Limite de valor para operações matemáticas

Tags: mysql, sql, select, matemática

Estou uma dúvida em relação a seguinte situação:

Tenho dois valores não armazenados em tabela.

```
Valor 1: 9223372036854775806 (Onde este é o valor máximo de um tipo de dado BIGINT)
Valor 2: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 (Um número qualquer gigantesco)
```

Ao efetuar a seguinte operação...

```
SELECT 9223372036854775807 + 1
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Error Code: 1690. BIGINT value is out of range in '(9223372036854775807 + 1)'
```

Já na seguinte operação, funciona normalmente...

```
SELECT 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 +1
```

Resultado:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Pergunto...

Se o limite para o BIGINT é de 9223372036854775807, pq não ocorre erro na segunda operação?

Comment: *(só para saber)* O segundo select não funciona no SQL Server, dá o erro: `... está fora do intervalo de representação numérica do computador (a precisão máxima é 38)`

Comment: No caso, os mesmos estão sendo efetuados no MySQL.